# Are the morphisms of a star-autonomous category superfluous?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $(C,\otimes,I,\ast)$ be a (symmetric, say) [star-autonomous category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/star-autonomous+category). Then $C$ comes equipped with a lax symmetric monoidal functor $|-|_C := Hom_C(I,-) : C \to Set$. The general hom-sets of $C$ can be deduced from $|-|_C$ as $Hom_C(x,y) = |[x,y]| = |(x \otimes y^\ast)^\ast|_C$. This suggest that perhaps the category structure on $C$ is a bit redundant.

So define a *pre-star-autonomous category* to comprise the following data:

1. a symmetric monoidal groupoid $(C_0, \otimes, I)$;
2. a strong monoidal (2,1)-equivalence $(-)^\ast : C_0^{rev} \to C_0$ such that the composite $(-)^\ast \circ ((-)^\ast)^{rev}$ is coherently symmetric monoidally isomorphic to the identity $C_0 \to C_0$;
3. a lax symmetric monoidal (2,1)-functor $|-|_C : C_0 \to (Grpd,\times,1)$

Here $C_0^{rev}$ is $C_0$ with the reverse monoidal structure, where $a \otimes^{rev} b = b \otimes a$.

Then, I'm wondering about the following

**Question 1:** Is the forgetful functor from star autonomous categories to pre-star-autonomous categories faithful? Faithful and locally fully faithful? Conservative?

**Question 2:** How can one reconstruct a star-autonomous category from the underlying pre-star-autonomous category (perhaps with some additional data)?

That is, I'm wondering if additional data is needed to recover the composition and identities in $C$ from the underlying pre-star-autonomous category $C_0$. If so, what data, and how is the reconstruction done?

Comment: Your first paragraph is equally true of any closed monoidal category, and indeed of any closed category.  I thought a bit about how to define a closed category without being given the morphisms [here](https://ncatlab.org/michaelshulman/show/closed%20category).  I was using a set of objects rather than a groupoid (the invertible morphisms are just as redundant as the noninvertible ones).  But it got kind of messy, and I realized I really wanted a "prounital" notion of closed category, and then after writing down the latter I never went back to it.